# Не стартует war собранный при помощи Gradle

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, tomcat, gradle

Сервер выдаёт вот такой лог

> C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\bin\catalina.bat run [2017-07-13
>   12:17:25,710] Artifact Gradle : com.leganas.gradle_web :
>   MyFirsgGWeb-1.0.war (exploded): Server is not connected. Deploy is not
>   available. Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   "C:\Users\AndreyLS.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_MyFirsgGWeb"
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22" Using
>   CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\temp" Using JRE_HOME:
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131" Using CLASSPATH:
>   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.915 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.917 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   9.0.0.0 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Windows 7 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   6.1 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.918 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_131-b11 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.919 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.919 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\AndreyLS.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_MyFirsgGWeb
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.919 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.919 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\AndreyLS.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_MyFirsgGWeb\conf\logging.properties
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.920 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.920 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.920
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.920 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:26.920 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.921 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:26.921 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.921
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.921 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\AndreyLS.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_MyFirsgGWeb
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.921 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:26.922 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\temp 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:26.922 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.12] using APR version
>   [1.5.2]. 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.922 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. 13-Jul-2017 12:17:26.922 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:27.989 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017] 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:28.146 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 13-Jul-2017
>   12:17:28.165 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.168 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.171 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.172 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 1676 ms 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.205 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service [Catalina] 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.206 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.224 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.244 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] 13-Jul-2017 12:17:28.248 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 75 ms
>   Connected to server [2017-07-13 12:17:28,384] Artifact Gradle :
>   com.leganas.gradle_web : MyFirsgGWeb-1.0.war (exploded): Artifact is
>   being deployed, please wait... 13-Jul-2017 12:17:29.910 INFO [RMI TCP
>   Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   13-Jul-2017 12:17:29.913 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:740)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of
>   type [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5084)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     ... 42 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:508)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1087)
>     ... 46 more
>
> 13-Jul-2017 12:17:29.917 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method manageApp  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>   [2017-07-13 12:17:29,945] Artifact Gradle : com.leganas.gradle_web :
>   MyFirsgGWeb-1.0.war (exploded): Error during artifact deployment. See
>   server log for details.   at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> 13-Jul-2017 12:17:29.918 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method createStandardContext 
>   javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method
>   manageApp     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     ... 33 more

вот содержимое build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6'
    compile 'javaee:javaee-api:5'
    compile 'javax:javaee-web-api:6.0'
}
```

в итоговом war файле успешно появляется папка lib со всем зависимыми библиотеками

кстати с Maven таже проблема 
если собирать в ручную то всё работает :( , подскажите куда смотреть

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Comment: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available. Вы хотите запустить сразу на сервере?

Comment: вы не собираете при помощи  gradle - вы собираете при помощи IDE. вот в настройки IDE и надо смотреть.

Comment: что значит я не собираю при помощи gradle ? я указал в конфигурации запуска выполнять Gradle Task в место обычного Build, в качестве объекта для Deploiment выбираю то что получилось после сборки. WAR

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов решения вашей проблемы

1. Удалите файл setenv.sh в $CATALINA_HOME/bin
2. Удалите папку .idea переимпортите проект и попробуйте

Наверняка дело в неправильных опциях JAVA_OPTS,а именно настройках environment, т.к. они конфликтуют с настройками IDEA